# how to point rubygems to use ruby 1.9.1?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

[Debian squeeze]

It has been surprisingly difficult to find an answer for this.

I had ruby v1.9.1 installed (/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1), but after I then installed rubygems, it also installed ruby1.8 (/usr/bin/ruby1.8), and all the commands I run on gem (gem install ..., rails ...) are all using ruby v1.8.

```
~/proj/rails/demo# bundle show sqlite3
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4
```

How do I get rubygems and rails to use the v1.9.1 which I have installed, instead of v1.8?

(side note: I did install rvm using "gem install rvm", but after I did that, I am not able to execute rvm, what's up with that?)

Answer (score 2):

Did you update /etc/alternatives?  On the ubuntu side of things, you'd run "sudo update-alternatives", and tell the system what the symlink for "/usr/bin/ruby", "/usr/bin/gem", etc., actually point to.  I'm not sure if "update-alternatives" is in Debian, but there should be a similar method of pointing at the version you want.

Hmm.  This is a bit old, but is probably applicable:

http://kangaroobox.blogspot.com/2009/12/switching-ruby-platforms-on-debian.html

Answer (score 1):

On Debian the `rubygems` package is just a meta-package which depends on `rubygems1.8`, the same way `ruby` just depends on `ruby1.8`. Thus, if you want rubygems for 1.9, you need to install `rubygems1.9`. The `gem` command (as all other potential executables like `ruby`, `irb` or `ri`) is just a symlink pointing to the preferred version like `gem1.8`. You can use those directly or you can use `update-alternatives` to set the preferred version.

Regarding RVM, it's true that there is a gem but it contains just some helpers for RVM. RVM doesn't require a pre-installed ruby. In fact, often it is used as the single way to install rubies on systems.

To actual install RVM, run

```
bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
```

as described on [RVM's install guide](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/). Please refer to it for more information about various install variants.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RVM (Ruby Version Manager), which can switch ruby versions easily.

To shift to Ruby version 1.9.1, try

```
rvn use 1.9.1
```

to make this version default, use

```
rvn use 1.9.1 --default
```

If you need to learn about basics of rvm, please follow this tutorial, which explains some more details about how to use RVM.

http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/basics/